# Folium choropleth map not colouring from geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, folium

I have a geopandas dataframe (dfg) with the following structure

```
lsoa11cd           object
A8                float64
OBJECTID            int64
LSOA11CD           object
LSOA11NM           object
LSOA11NMW          object
Shape__Area       float64
Shape__Length     float64
geometry        geometry
```

I have tried to generate a choropleth via folium, but all the regions are showing as a flat grey.

```
    m = folium.Map(
    location=[52.2405, -0.9027],
    
    zoom_start=13  
)
folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=dfg,
    name ='choropleth',
    data=dfg,
    columns=['LSOA11CD', 'A8'],
    
    Fill_colour='RdPu',
 
    fill_opacity=0.5,
    line_opacity=0.2


).add_to(m)



folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

All the regions draw correctly, but all the same colour.

It works nicely using the plot function

```
dfg.plot(column='A8')
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the `key_on` parameter in the `folium.Choropleth`, which is basically the link between your GeoJson and your pandas DataFrame.

It uses your GeoJson keys to know where to do the join. It can be something like `'feature.id'`, but you will have to provide an example of your GeoJson so that I can tell you the exact key.